# Do non-clustered indexes slow down inserts?

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-indexes

I'm working in Sql Server 2005. I have an event log table that tracks user actions, and I want to make sure that inserts into the table are as fast as possible. Currently the table doesn't have any indexes. Does adding a single non-clustered index slow down inserts at all? Or is it only clustered indexes that slow down inserts? Or should I just add a clustered index and not worry about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indexes, clustered or non-clustered,will always slow down inserts as SQL has to maintain both the table and index. This slowdown is in an "absolute" sense and you may not notice it.  I would add whatever indexes are necessary to retrieve your data.

Comment: Assuming that retrieval is more important than speed of writes... let's say your capturing data from a UDP stream and any slowdown in writing means a loss of packet capture... but you'll only need to query in the invent of contact from ET...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, any index will take a little bit of time to keep up to date when doing `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE` operations. The more indices you have, the more time we're talking about.

But ultimately it depends on what's more important to you - good query performance (then add indices as needed), or good insert performance (then have as few indices as possible).

Which operation do you perform more often??

Comment: I would like to know what happen's if both matters at the same time.I am having a data ware housing kind database,I need very frequent inserts also I need to perform report queries out of them.
Report queries needs some indexes to perform well,but this could slow down the insertion statements at the same time.

Im using MySQL(MISAM).